# Which countries do not have the concept of certain ‘breakfast food’?

Tags: food-and-drink

I recently visited Ukraine with a friend. One night we stayed at a hotel that served meals. In the morning, we came down to breakfast and were surprised to be served a carbonara-type pasta dish–not what we would normally have considered breakfast food. We asked our guide, and he said that Ukrainians don't separate foods into different meals and just eat whatever, whenever.

**Which countries do not have the concept of certain ‘breakfast food’?**

[This article](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/what-people-eat-for-breakfast-around-the-world-a6730126.html) goes through common breakfasts from different countries, but most seem to be uniquely breakfast-y (except for Korea).

[This one](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2019/05/what-is-breakfast/589411/) claims that the US is in the minority in having unique breakfast foods and suggests that ‘poorer people everywhere, especially in places like India and China, eat the same kind of food for meal after meal’.

Ukraine doesn't get a mention on [the Wikipedia article on ‘Breakfast’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast), so I can't even verify what the guide said about it–maybe it was just the hotel we were in's approach–to be fair, the hotel *was* in the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone so I can imagine food options might be limited.

Comment: You could try the cookery SE.

Comment: @badjohn I did wonder which would be more appropriate when I asked the question; I've [re-asked the question there](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103185/which-countries-do-not-have-the-concept-of-certain-breakfast-food) too.