# Is breakfast in the Balkans only coffee?

Tags: food-and-drink, local-customs, balkans

I went through Albania, Macedonia, and Bulgaria recently, and noticed that in the morning, the local cafe are full of people but everyone only orders a cup espresso or a bottle of water. Is that the norm (ie. not eating any solid food for breakfast) or am I missing something?

Comment: There was an intersting question a year ago [Which countries do not have the concept of certain ‘breakfast food’?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149072/which-countries-do-not-have-the-concept-of-certain-breakfast-food) - which was closed.

Comment: They eat breakfast at home, then go out for coffee ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can speak only for Bulgaria, but I assume it‘s simular for the other two countries. Many cafes don‘t offer any food or just some cakes, people go there just to meet each other, to see and to be seen. Sometimes people stay there for hours and drink only one cup of coffee.
They preffer to eat at home, because it‘s cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

Often it's common to have a coffee *before* breakfast in the Balkans, apparently. However, there are a lot of breakfasts there too, eg just look at a recipe website:

http://www.balkanfoodrecipes.com/category/dishes/breakfast/

and see items like kaymak, ceshket, popara and more.

Comment: You mentioned "apparently" so I was wondering if you have observed people eating such foods for breakfast.

Comment: Yes. The 'apparently' was there mainly because the idea of eating anything before I've had my coffee is shocking ;)  Also when I was there I was younger and mainly on a boat in Croatia, and I often used to wake up post breakfast and just need my coffee :)